# Finding data in a text file?

Tags: java

I want to have some kind of file containing text, kinda like this:

```
John.file: 
Name= John
Age = 333
```

And in my program, I'd like to somehow make a Person with this data, kinda like:

```
Person p = new Person(John.file);
```

What would be some good alternatives to find the data in the file so that I can add, like "333" to the the Person p's age-variable? I was thinking of trying out the regex api unless there are other alternatives!

Comment: what is `John.file` when you pass it as argument to the `Person`'s constructor?? a String or something else?? i.e. what type of argument does the `Person`'s constructor takes??

Comment: The simplest approach is the way you are going. Storing information in a `file` and retrieving and assigning the attributes to corresponding variables. Just a note - if you want things simpler, just have the important stuff stored in your `file` , like `John,`333`,etc. Avoid `Name=`. This is if you want to make your way really easy, and the `file` solely hasn't any purpose but to be relevant for your Java program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're looking to do with the properties file functionality that is part of the JDK.  See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) for more information.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("/my/path/John.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
System.out.println(properties.getProperty("Name")); // Prints John
```

For completeness, here are the contents of /my/path/John.properties.

```
Name=John
Age=333
```

Comment: `// Prints John`  Or possibly `null` if the catch was invoked. ;)  It would be true if it was the code statement immediately following `properties.load(..`

Comment: @AndrewThompson Point taken!  Just going for extreme simplicity in order to demonstrate with the example.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use XML for this. You can use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) to deserialize the XML into a Java class. For a simple class like the one you described, this would be a trivial matter. The XML would look something like:

```
<Person>
<Name>John</Name>
<Age>333</Age>
</Person>
```

Comment: i m sorry but i think you are un-necessarily complicating the things for OP!!

Comment: @WickeD Nothing complicated about this. In the long run, it'll make things easier.

Comment: i m just saying that from what i can gather from OP's question he is _relatively_ new to java and may find it confusing!

Comment: @WickeD You may be right about that. But I think this is the easiest way to do this without making a fragile and volatile custom parser.

Answer (score 2):

XML, [JSON](http://json.org/java/), customized Properties file, or your own parser, maybe based on [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) ?